Cómo redirigir al la carpeta de producción de vue 3 en una aplicación express de Nodejs
teniendo esta estructura en la app de express, donde no hay ningún fichero del proyecto de Vue a excepción de la carpeta dist/ que es el bundle de producción, no consigo redirigir la configuración de la aplicación para que utilize el router configurado en Vue recibiendo esto en consola cuando despliego el proyecto:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
esta es la estructura del proyecto ->
/opt/apps/api
├── README.md
├── bin
│   └── www
├── dist
│   ├── FAVICON IQ.svg
│   ├── LOGO IQ TEST.svg
│   ├── Master.svg
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── 607806bb9881850fd20e0082_check-bd6e4e52.png
│   │   ├── AvarageInfoSection-8583aab8.js
│   │   ├── DancingScript-VariableFont_wght-b2adec2a.ttf
│   │   ├── GeogrotesqueCyr-ExtraLight-01c38232.ttf
│   │   ├── GeogrotesqueCyr-LightItalic-885151fd.ttf
│   │   ├── IlustrationSection-be34f0f9.js
│   │   ├── PlanSection-b0a70cc2.js
│   │   ├── WorkSection-f4c91671.js
│   │   ├── certificado_mod-b592380e.png
│   │   ├── check-53578c29.svg
│   │   ├── diploma-e39d87d2.png
│   │   ├── index-ac33dd0f.css
│   │   ├── informe-45e45c16.jpg
│   │   ├── logo-8fbaec84.png
│   │   ├── logo2-9f86691e.png
│   │   ├── logotres-50e2efe2.png
│   │   ├── main-c01e392c.js
│   │   ├── pagos-0d0eba6e.png
│   │   ├── reporte-d6237620.jpg
│   │   └── test-340586ea.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── Acknowledgement.otf
│   │   ├── Amble-Bold.ttf
│   │   ├── Arvo-Bold.ttf
│   │   ├── Heading-Pro-Bold-trial.ttf
│   │   ├── Heading-Pro-ExtraBold-trial.ttf
│   │   ├── Heading-Pro-Heavy-trial.ttf
│   │   ├── Heading-Pro-Light-trial.ttf
│   │   ├── Inter-Black.ttf
│   │   ├── InterDisplay-Light.ttf
│   │   ├── Montserrat-BlackItalic.ttf
│   │   └── RobotoMono-ExtraLight.ttf
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── 115.svg
│   │   ├── 130.svg
│   │   ├── 69.svg
│   │   ├── 70.svg
│   │   ├── 85.svg
│   │   ├── amex.svg
│   │   ├── ar.svg
│   │   ├── asistent.svg
│   │   ├── au.svg
│   │   ├── average.svg
│   │   ├── back.svg
│   │   ├── be.svg
│   │   ├── ca.svg
│   │   ├── check.svg
│   │   ├── check2.svg
│   │   ├── check3.svg
│   │   ├── cn.svg
│   │   ├── commited.svg
│   │   ├── concentration.svg
│   │   ├── congratulations.svg
│   │   ├── flags
│   │   │   ├── catalonia.webp
│   │   │   ├── francy.webp
│   │   │   ├── germany.webp
│   │   │   ├── italy.webp
│   │   │   ├── portugal.webp
│   │   │   ├── spain.webp
│   │   │   ├── united-kingdom.webp
│   │   │   └── united-states.webp
│   │   ├── flat_01.svg
│   │   ├── flat_02.svg
│   │   ├── flat_03.svg
│   │   ├── games
│   │   │   ├── faster (1).png
│   │   │   ├── faster (2).png
│   │   │   ├── faster-1.png
│   │   │   ├── faster-2.png
│   │   │   ├── games.svg
│   │   │   ├── h pe (2) (1).png
│   │   │   ├── h pe (3).png
│   │   │   ├── h pe (4).png
│   │   │   ├── h pe (5).png
│   │   │   ├── h pe (6).png
│   │   │   ├── h-pe-2-1.png
│   │   │   ├── h-pe-4.png
│   │   │   ├── h-pe-5.png
│   │   │   ├── h-pe-6.png
│   │   │   ├── hpe-3.png
│   │   │   └── play-svgrepo-com.svg
│   │   ├── grafic.svg
│   │   ├── grafic2.webp
│   │   ├── hand.svg
│   │   ├── hero.svg
│   │   ├── hero2.svg
│   │   ├── ilustration.svg
│   │   ├── logic.svg
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   ├── logotres.png
│   │   ├── m_01.svg
│   │   ├── m_02.svg
│   │   ├── m_03.svg
│   │   ├── m_04.svg
│   │   ├── mastercard.svg
│   │   ├── membership.svg
│   │   ├── memory.svg
│   │   ├── mixed.png
│   │   ├── people
│   │   │   ├── 1.svg
│   │   │   ├── 10.svg
│   │   │   ├── 11.svg
│   │   │   ├── 12.svg
│   │   │   ├── 2.svg
│   │   │   ├── 3.svg
│   │   │   ├── 4.svg
│   │   │   ├── 5.svg
│   │   │   ├── 6.svg
│   │   │   ├── 7.svg
│   │   │   ├── 8.svg
│   │   │   ├── 9.svg
│   │   │   ├── f_1.svg
│   │   │   └── f_2.webp
│   │   ├── people_1.svg
│   │   ├── rate_people.svg
│   │   ├── reaction.svg
│   │   ├── refresh.svg
│   │   ├── skill.svg
│   │   ├── speed.svg
│   │   ├── start.svg
│   │   ├── uk.svg
│   │   ├── united-kingdom.webp
│   │   ├── united-states.webp
│   │   ├── usa.svg
│   │   ├── visa.svg
│   │   ├── visa.webp
│   │   ├── vite.svg
│   │   └── vue.svg
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo.png
│   ├── mapas
│   │   ├── chicago.png
│   │   ├── francia.png
│   │   ├── londres.png
│   │   ├── madrid.png
│   │   ├── mexico.png
│   │   ├── paris.png
│   │   └── portugal.png
│   └── visa.png
├── iq-testonline.org -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/iq-testonline.org
├── kill.sh
├── nodemon.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── public
│   ├── assets -> /opt/apps/frontendProd/dist/assets/
│   ├── diploma
│   │   ├── 66f93c45853fcb62856ecb4c.pdf
│   │   ├── 66f94d4bd5e2da67e786a85e.pdf
│   │   ├── 66fa0a11566b30c766e9353c.pdf
│   │   ├── 66fed8c2916ad090df1fbd8e.pdf
│   │   ├── 66ff8495916ad090df1fbdfe.pdf
│   │   ├── 6709ebab916ad090df1fbf17.pdf
│   │   ├── 671d437d0489fcf31796dcba.pdf
│   │   ├── 67222fec0489fcf31796e1f4.pdf
│   │   ├── 672236120489fcf31796e230.pdf
│   │   ├── 6723a01b0489fcf31796e378.pdf
│   │   ├── 6723a07a0489fcf31796e398.pdf
│   │   ├── 67274dde0489fcf31796e4a6.pdf
│   │   ├── 672ba81b0489fcf31796e653.pdf
│   │   └── usuario.pdf
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── embassy-bt.ttf
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   └── questions
│   │       ├── Q1
│   │       │   ├── Q1-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q1-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q1-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q1-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q1-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q1-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q1-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q10
│   │       │   ├── Q10-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q10-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q10-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q10-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q10-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q10-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q10-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q11
│   │       │   ├── Q11-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q11-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q11-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q11-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q11-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q11-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q11-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q12
│   │       │   ├── Q12-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q12-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q12-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q12-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q12-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q12-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q12-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q13
│   │       │   ├── Q13-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q13-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q13-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q13-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q13-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q13-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q13-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q14
│   │       │   ├── Q14-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q14-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q14-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q14-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q14-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q14-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q14-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q15
│   │       │   ├── Q15-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q15-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q15-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q15-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q15-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q15-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q15-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q16
│   │       │   ├── Q16-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q16-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q16-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q16-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q16-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q16-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q16-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q17
│   │       │   ├── Q17-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q17-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q17-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q17-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q17-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q17-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q17-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q18
│   │       │   ├── Q18-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q18-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q18-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q18-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q18-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q18-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q18-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q19
│   │       │   ├── Q19-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q19-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q19-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q19-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q19-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q19-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q19-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q2
│   │       │   ├── Q2-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q2-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q2-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q2-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q2-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q2-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q2-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q20
│   │       │   ├── Q20-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q20-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q20-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q20-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q20-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q20-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q20-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q3
│   │       │   ├── Q3-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q3-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q3-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q3-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q3-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q3-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q3-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q4
│   │       │   ├── Q4-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q4-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q4-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q4-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q4-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q4-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q4-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q5
│   │       │   ├── Q5-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q5-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q5-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q5-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q5-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q5-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q5-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q6
│   │       │   ├── Q6-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q6-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q6-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q6-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q6-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q6-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q6-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q7
│   │       │   ├── Q7-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q7-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q7-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q7-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q7-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q7-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q7-07.svg
│   │       ├── Q8
│   │       │   ├── Q8-01.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q8-02.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q8-03.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q8-04.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q8-05.svg
│   │       │   ├── Q8-06.svg
│   │       │   └── Q8-07.svg
│   │       └── Q9
│   │           ├── Q9-01.svg
│   │           ├── Q9-02.svg
│   │           ├── Q9-03.svg
│   │           ├── Q9-04.svg
│   │           ├── Q9-05.svg
│   │           ├── Q9-06.svg
│   │           └── Q9-07.svg
│   ├── img -> /opt/apps/frontend/dist/img/
│   ├── index-34e87464.js -> /opt/apps/frontendProd/dist/assets/index-34e87464.js
│   ├── index.html -> /opt/apps/frontend/dist/index.html
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   └── stripe.js
│   ├── logo.png -> /opt/apps/frontend/dist/logo.png
│   ├── mapas -> /opt/apps/frontend/dist/mapas/
│   ├── result
│   │   ├── 66f93c45853fcb62856ecb4c.pdf
│   │   ├── 66f94d4bd5e2da67e786a85e.pdf
│   │   ├── 66fa0a11566b30c766e9353c.pdf
│   │   ├── 66fed8c2916ad090df1fbd8e.pdf
│   │   ├── 66ff8495916ad090df1fbdfe.pdf
│   │   ├── 6709ebab916ad090df1fbf17.pdf
│   │   ├── 671d437d0489fcf31796dcba.pdf
│   │   ├── 67222fec0489fcf31796e1f4.pdf
│   │   ├── 672236120489fcf31796e230.pdf
│   │   ├── 6723a01b0489fcf31796e378.pdf
│   │   ├── 6723a07a0489fcf31796e398.pdf
│   │   ├── 67274dde0489fcf31796e4a6.pdf
│   │   ├── 672ba81b0489fcf31796e653.pdf
│   │   └── usuario.pdf
│   ├── stylesheets
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   └── stylep.css
│   └── template
│       ├── Archive.zip
│       ├── be
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── ca
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── de
│       │   ├── IQ CERTIFICATE (2)-6.pdf
│       │   ├── REPORT IQ TEST DE.pdf
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── en
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── es
│       │   ├── REPORT IQ TEST ES.pdf
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── fr
│       │   ├── IQ CERTIFICATE (2)-4.pdf
│       │   ├── REPORT IQ TEST FR.pdf
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── it
│       │   ├── IQ CERTIFICATE (2)-5.pdf
│       │   ├── REPORT IQ TEST FR.pdf
│       │   ├── REPORT IQ TEST IT.pdf
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── no
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       ├── pt
│       │   ├── REPORT IQ TEST PT.pdf
│       │   ├── diploma_template.pdf
│       │   └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
│       └── sv
│           ├── diploma_template.pdf
│           └── reporte-sin-datos.pdf
├── r.sh
├── src
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── config
│   │   └── i18n.js
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── emailController.js
│   │   ├── loginController.js
│   │   ├── orderController.js
│   │   ├── paymentController.js
│   │   ├── questionController.js
│   │   ├── recordatorioController.js
│   │   └── userController.js
│   ├── database
│   │   └── config.js
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── helper.js
│   │   └── mailer.js
│   ├── locales
│   │   ├── ca.json
│   │   ├── de.json
│   │   ├── en.json
│   │   ├── es.json
│   │   ├── fr.json
│   │   ├── it.json
│   │   ├── no.json
│   │   ├── pt.json
│   │   └── sv.json
│   ├── middlewares
│   │   ├── authenticationMiddleware.js
│   │   └── languageMiddleware.js
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── answer.js
│   │   ├── login.js
│   │   ├── order.js
│   │   ├── question.js
│   │   └── user.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── contact.js
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── login.js
│   │   ├── order.js
│   │   ├── payments.js
│   │   ├── question.js
│   │   ├── reminder.js
│   │   ├── token.js
│   │   └── users.js
│   └── views
│       ├── error.hbs
│       ├── index.hbs
│       ├── layout.hbs
│       ├── payment
│       │   ├── cancel.hbs
│       │   ├── checkout.hbs
│       │   └── success.hbs
│       └── template
│           └── email
│               ├── adminContact.hbs
│               ├── alta.hbs
│               ├── baja.hbs
│               ├── baja_admin.hbs
│               ├── clientContact.hbs
│               ├── paid.hbs
│               ├── reminder.hbs
│               ├── reset.hbs
│               └── success.hbs
├── start.sh
└── tsconfig.json 

En el fichero de entrada de la app.js tengo esta configuración para el uso de los ficheros de dist/ ->
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),{
   maxAge: '1y', // un año en segundos
 }));

 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request to:', req.url); 
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist', 'index.html'));
 });

Alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo configurar la app correctamente?
